# How to assign a variable in e.g. a ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: foreach, swiftui, swift5

is it possible to set a variable in SwiftUI e.g. in a ForEach like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var test: Int

    var body: some View {

        List {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) {
                Text("\($0)…")

                test = $0 // how to realise this?
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I can not bring this to live, I'm getting an error like:

```
Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
```

Comment: If you need to do this, you are doing something wrong. The question you should be asking yourself is "Why do I need to assign to `test`?"

Comment: In the loop I will have some sections. And I need to groupe the items dynamically so I need always to check the prev. item. therefor I want to store it somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign to `test` anything from anywhere *inside* your `ContentView`, because it is struct and, so, `self` is immutable, but you will be able to do something like in the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
//    var test: Int // cannot be assigned, because self is immutable

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { (i) -> Text in
                let test = i // calculate something intermediate
                return Text("\(test)…")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using a @State var definition and apply the value from a task inside your foreach.
Example:

```
struct MyView: View {

@State var curGameDate: String = ""
var gameSection: GameSectionDto

var body: some View {

       Text(curGameDate) // <- use the state var outside the loop
                .padding(.bottom, 2.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color("DarkGrey"))
                .font(.system(size: 15.0))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)


    ForEach(gameSection.listItems, id: \.gameIdentifier) { game in
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            GameRowView(game: game, isResult: gameSection.result)
                    .background(RoundedCorners(color: .white, tl: 10, tr: 10, bl: 10, br: 10))
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5.0)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(proxy.frame (in: .global).minX / -10), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3),
                            radius: 8, x: 0, y: 6)
        } //: GeoReader
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5.0)
                .padding(.top, 5.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 25.0)
                .task { // assign it in the foreach
                    self.curGameDate = game.gameDate.getDateString(pattern: "eeee, dd.MM.yyyy")
                } //: task

    } //: ForEach
    
}
```

}